# Error-Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Tags: azure-aks, azure-powershell

[image]Hope you can help me with a problem trying to execute a script block

```
Get-AzAksVersion -Location CanadaCentral | Where-Object -Property OrchestratorVersion -gt 1.22.11, IsPreview -ne $true
```

trying to get the versions greater than the current version and excluding the preview version, getting error as Parameter set cannot be resolved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this command help `Get-AzAksVersion -Location CanadaCentral | where-Object {($_.OrchestratorVersion -gt '1.22.15') -and ($_.IsPreview -ne 'True')}`. Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/7p8ugw4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

```
Get-AzAksVersion -Location CanadaCentral | Where-Object -Property OrchestratorVersion -gt 1.22.11, IsPreview -ne $true
```

[image]

**To resolve the error, try the below command:**

```
Get-AzAksVersion -Location CanadaCentral | where-Object {($_.OrchestratorVersion -gt '1.22.15') -and ($_.IsPreview -ne 'True')}
```

[image]

Comment: When i was trying from azure runbook using **Get-AzAksVersion -Location canadacentral | where-Object {($_.OrchestratorVersion -gt '1.23.12') -and ($_.IsPreview -ne 'True')}** output is 1.23.8, 1.24.3, 1.24.6 -it shouldn't give the 1.23.8

Comment: Can you include the snip of what you are trying?

Comment: added the screenshot which im trying in my environment.